# Are SPDC photons always identical?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics

If entangled pair is created by SPDC expescially by BBO crystal are they automatically identical e.g. indistinguishable? If the state is HV+VH do they get identical by disentangling them and then rotate H to V of one of them?

Answer (score 0):

Great question! There are various types of SPDC and they do not all operate quite the same.

a) One of the most common types of SPDC from 2 non-linear Barium Borate (BBo) crystals producing 2 overlapping cones.  This is called Type I PDC (PDC is the same thing as SPDC). See [Entangled photons, nonlocality and Bell inequalities in the undergraduate laboratory](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0205171) - figure 2.  These photons are polarization entangled and correlated.  The Bell state is usually HH> + VV>

b) Another is called Type II PDC: [Generation of correlated photon pairs in type-II
parametric down conversion – revisited.](https://xqp.physik.uni-muenchen.de/publications/files/articles_2001/journmodopt_48_1997.pdf) This also produces 2 cones, but these only overlap in a small region. These photons are polarization entangled but are anti-correlated.  The Bell state is often HV> - VH>.

Now, the interesting thing is that experimenters seek photon pairs that have the highest quality of entanglement using either technique.  That can be found when the cones are approximately 2.5 or 3.0 degrees off angle.  At the optimum angle, there is very nearly exact matching (and entanglement) of output photons as to polarization and wavelength.

But that is not a requirement for them to be entangled.  There is what might be called "wiggle room" for lack of a better term. For example, there are also cones that can be found at +/- 1 degree (or whatever) from the optimal angle.  Those too will contain entangled pairs.  However, the entanglements quality degrades as you get further and further from optimal.

This are not exact numbers, I am making this up to give you the idea (since it varies by setup). If you had 99.5% entanglement at optimum, you might have 85% entanglement if you use something less optimal.  When the photons exit in a distinguishable fashion (i.e. sub-optimal), that percentage will not be entangled.

To be more specific still: a typical input laser generates 405 nm wavelength photons. In the ideal (optimal) case, both of the output photons are at 810 nm. But as you go off optimal, you get pairs in which 1 photon might be 800 nm and the other is 820. **They may or may not still be polarization entangled, even if the wavelengths are different.**

1. So the actual answer to your first question: they are not "automatically" identical.  It takes work to get them to be as indistinguishable as possible.  Current technology does a great job of this.
2. For your second question: they are created in a correlated or anti-correlated state depending on the setup.  You definitely want to keep them entangled until they arrive at the final detectors.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot. Are there any gadgets to get rid of non correlated photons? Slits at 3 grades will do the work of course but than one gets dispersion. Or the devices are equipped with them?

Comment: If the state is VH+HV how one can prove experimentally that two photons are identical?

Comment: @Mercury Regarding non-entangled photons: Often a filter is used to make sure that the desired wavelength (say 810 nm) is all that gets through. This helps.  But it really goes back to proper adjustment of the setup to collect pairs from the optimal zones.

Comment: @Mercury Regarding identical photons: Surprisingly, there is no actual requirement that entangled photons be identical in any respect. They can have opposite polarization - such as when in the state VH + HV. Pairs produced by PDC usually have nearly the same wavelength (as discussed). However, there are other sources of polarization entangled photons that have completely different wavelengths. The early experiments on entanglement used such sources. And in fact: you can entangle completely different particle types on the polarization basis (again not via PDC).